# Why do higher fluorine oxyanions not exist?

Tags: ions, covalent-compounds, halides

I asked this question from my teacher and he said that's because fluorine has a high electronegativity and does not form dative bond with oxygen. That's why only hypofluorite $\ce{FO-}$ exists and not $\ce{FO_n-}$ ($n = 2,3,4$).

But then I was wondering why $\ce{BF4-}$ exists. And according to this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroboric_acid) article, fluorine does form dative bond.

so why the anions in the title do not exist?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't find the word "dative" in your linked article. Could you provide a quote?

Comment: I thought this reaction involves dative bonds: "Three equivalents of HF react to give the intermediate boron trifluoride and the fourth gives fluoroboric acid:

B(OH)3 + 4 HF → H3O+ + BF−
4 + 2 H2O"

Comment: I would say that it is because the electronegativity difference in $\ce{F-O}$ is too small, but I would wait for people much more knowledgeable than me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two factors at play here:

1. Fluorine is more electronegative than oxygen. In oxyanions, the central atom carries a substantial positive charge due to the oxygen atom pulling away electron density. In oxyfluorides, oxygen actually *donates* electron density to fluorine and oxygen would logically be the central atom. There are theoretical studies into [$\ce{OF3+}$](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2FS0022-1139%2899%2900139-6) but no successful syntheses yet.
2. The fluorine atom is *tiny*, even by period 2 standards. There's simply not enough space around the proximity of the atom to fit three or more other atoms.

Answer (score 1):

In the hypothetical fluorine- and oxygen- containing ions, F is the central atom. However, to have 2 or more O atoms bonded to it means that F will have more than 8 valence electrons. This is impossible as F is a period 2 element and has no energetically accessible orbitals for octet expansion.

This is because F is more electronegative than O - so you're right about F not donating electron pairs to O, hence F forms only covalent bonds here.

As for $\ce{BF_4^-}$ , B in $\ce{BF_3}$ is electron-deficient with 6 valence electrons and will gladly accept an electron pair from the nucleophile $\ce{F-}$ .

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: About the first part I think dative bond is not the same as valence shell expansion. About the second part; you mean BF3 is more electron-deficient than oxygen?

Comment: Yes you're right - to clarify, F does not form dative bonds with O, or expand its octet by forming covalent bonds with O.

Comment: For your second question - yes, as B is bonded to 3 electronegative F atoms. But the point was that the octet structure of O and B affects the bonding. O has electrons available for covalent bonding unlike B in BF3 which has an empty orbital to accept a lone pair from F to form a dative bond :)